# Zend Form and URL Parameters

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, parameters

I have a Zend form and a URL to this form.

The URL has 3 parameters firstname, lastname and email.
In my form i have 3 input fields that also has firstname, lastname and email.

Whenever I submit the form. It's getting the values from the URL parameters instead of the form input fields.

Is there a way to get values in the form?

I know that the parameters from url has same name as the form input fields*

URL: http://mywebsite.com/thank-you?key=e72671a8640b45c2401afe887b9b530a&**first_name**=First&**last_name**=User&**email**=user_3fdfsdfs@gmail.com

Zend action controller of the form:

```
$signupForm = new Application_Form_UserSignUp();
if ($signupForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams()))
        {

            $user = $this->_helper->model('Users')->createRow($signupForm->getValues());   
            if ($user->save())
            {
                Zend_Session::rememberMe(186400 * 14);
                Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write($user);
                $user->sendSignUpEmail();
                $this->getHelper('redirector')->gotoRoute(array(), 'invite');
                return;
            }
        }
$this->view->signupForm = $signupForm;
```

Zend form:

```
class Application_Form_UserSignUp extends Zend_Form
{
public $first_name, $last_name, $email, $submitButton;

public function init()
{
    $this->setName('signupForm'); 

    $this->first_name = $this->createElement('text', 'first_name')->setRequired(true);
    $this->last_name = $this->createElement('text', 'last_name')->setRequired(true);

    // Check if email is duplicated in database
    $noEmailExists = new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(
            array(
                'table' => 'users',
                'field' => 'email'
            )
        );
    $noEmailExists->setMessage('%value% is already used by another person, please try again with different email address', Zend_Validate_Db_Abstract::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND);

    $this->email = $this->createElement('text', 'email')
                     ->setLabel('Email')
                     ->addValidator($noEmailExists)
                     ->addValidator('EmailAddress')
                     ->setRequired(true);

    $this->submitButton = $this->createElement('button', 'save')
                            ->setLabel('Sign Up')
                            ->setAttrib('type', 'submit');

    $this->addElements(array($this->first_name, $this->last_name, $this->email, $this->submitButton));

    $elementDecorators = array(
        'ViewHelper'
    );
    $this->setElementDecorators($elementDecorators);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller Action you can pass values to Zend_Form object:

```
$form->populate($data);
```

OR
    $form->setDefaults($data);

Where populate() takes an array where the keys are the names of the form fields and array values are the field values.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.elements.values

Comment: I think I fix it. instead of $signupForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams()), I changed $signupForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())

Comment: Yes, for validation you only need POST vars, but if you want populate form with values filled before submit you must use populate.